# Getting all types that implement an interface in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda, .net-core

Using reflection, How can I get all types that implement some specific interface in **.NET Core**? I have noticed that the methods usable in .NET 4.6 are not available anymore.

For example, this code doesn't work.

```
var type = typeof(IMyInterface);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

It throws `The name 'AppDomain' does not exist in the current context` error.

Comment: I'm sure that code works fine, you just don't have an `AppDomain`.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth so How to include AppDomain? :D

Comment: What do you need it for? It's not usually something you mess with.

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth This is a pretty standard pattern for supporting plugins.

Comment: Hmm, no, you should not be writing code like this.  Sooner or later you'll end up using CoreRT and having to list those types anyway ahead-of-time.

Comment: @HansPassant That's not true. People might use Core in environments where they won't port to CoreRT. It is dismissive to assume everyone will be porting their code to CoreRT.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but a workaround is proposed in [this blog post](http://www.michael-whelan.net/replacing-appdomain-in-dotnet-core/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can do this way:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

foreach (System.Reflection.TypeInfo ti in ass.DefinedTypes)
{
    if (ti.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(yourInterface)))
    {
        ass.CreateInstance(ti.FullName) as yourInterface;
    }  
}
```

If you want types in all assemblies, just simply use the following to get all the references and do the above again:)

```
ass.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

Comment: That only gets the types within a single assembly, not all loaded assemblies.

Comment: Shorthand using LINQ

var types = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().DefinedTypes.Where(ti => ti.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(ILogger))).Select(m => m.FullName);

Answer (score 9):

The full code to get all classes that implement type 'T'

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var assemblies = assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    foreach (var assemblyName in assemblies)
    {
        assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

        foreach (var ti in assembly.DefinedTypes)
        {
            if (ti.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(T)))
            {
                yield return (T)assembly.CreateInstance(ti.FullName);
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In .NET Core 2.0, you can find all matching types in assemblies that were known at compile time (this does not work for dynamically loaded assemblies) like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllTypesOf<T>()
{
    var platform = Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString();
    var runtimeAssemblyNames = DependencyContext.Default.GetRuntimeAssemblyNames(platform);

    return runtimeAssemblyNames
        .Select(Assembly.Load)
        .SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes)
        .Where(t => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
```

This relies on the [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel/) package.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to get all loaded assemblies in .Net Core 1.0. [It seems a way to do this is planned for 1.1.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8806)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is tell to interface who are the objects that implement it with `[ServiceKnownTypeAttribute]` and when you need know the types that implement get by reflexion. Example:

```
public class TypeWithImplementOne : IMyInterface
{
  public string Hi()
  {
    return "hi";
  }

}
public class TypeWithImplementTwo : IMyInterface
{
   public string Hi()
  {
    return "hi";
  }
}
public interface IMyInterface{
{
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TypeWithImplementOne))]
  [ServiceKnownType(typeof(TypeWithImplementTwo))]

  string Hi();
}
```

And you can recover the types that implemented with:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetKnownTypes()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        Type interfaceType = typeof(IMyInterface);
        IEnumerable<CustomAttributeData> attributes = interfaceType.CustomAttributes
            .Where(t => t.AttributeType == typeof(ServiceKnownTypeAttribute));

        foreach (CustomAttributeData attribute in attributes)
        {
            IEnumerable<CustomAttributeTypedArgument> knownTypes = attribute.ConstructorArguments;
            foreach (CustomAttributeTypedArgument knownType in knownTypes)
            {
                result.Add(knownType.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        result.Sort();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want types in all assemblies, just simply use the following to get all the references and do the above again:)

```
ass.GetReferencedAssemblies()
```